# Backup hdfs directory from pseudo-distributed to local directory?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm playing around with HBase & Hadoop and have them running in pseudo-distributed mode on my machine. I have tables written to HBase that are stored in a 'hbase' directory on hdfs as shown below

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -ls /Found 3 items
drwxr-xr-x   - robocode supergroup          0 2013-04-17 11:48 /Users
drwxr-xr-x   - robocode supergroup          0 2013-04-17 11:26 /hbase
drwxr-xr-x   - robocode supergroup          0 2013-04-08 15:07 /usr
```

I want to backup this hbase directory from hdfs to a directory on my desktop so that I can restore it to hbase/hdfs at a later date. I'm using distcp as below, it seems to run fine but when it completes there is no sign of the hbase directory on my desktop

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase /Users/robocode/Desktop/

13/04/17 11:55:39 INFO tools.DistCp: srcPaths=[hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase]
13/04/17 11:55:39 INFO tools.DistCp: destPath=/Users/robocode/Desktop
13/04/17 11:55:39 INFO tools.DistCp: sourcePathsCount=40
13/04/17 11:55:39 INFO tools.DistCp: filesToCopyCount=17
13/04/17 11:55:39 INFO tools.DistCp: bytesToCopyCount=22.9k
13/04/17 11:55:40 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201304171125_0004
13/04/17 11:55:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/04/17 11:55:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201304171125_0004
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 20
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=11840
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=7105
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=673
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=24954
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=22417
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=18365
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   distcp
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Files copied=7
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes copied=17692
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes expected=17692
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Files skipped=10
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=39
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=85000192
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input bytes=7005
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=10
13/04/17 11:56:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=157
```

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: check the `/Users/robocode/Desktop/` path in HDFS, my guess is it's copied to HDFS. I'm not sure you can distcp to the local file system, you can try by prefixing with `file:///Users/robocode/Desktop/`

Comment: Right you were Chris! It was indeed coping it to HDFS but by prefixing it with `file:///` it copied it to the local file system. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mark this question as answered, as noted in the comments:

```
hadoop distcp hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase file:///Users/robocode/Desktop/
```